# Get Value from first Combobox and change value of second Combobox

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, python-3.6

Here I have two combobox, first is Homepage_List, second is Board_List.

What I want is that when I select one of the Homepage_List, the appropriate bd list appears in Board_List.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5 import uic,QtGui,QtCore

class Main_App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = uic.loadUi("mainwindow_for_parser.ui", self)

        self.ui.show()
        self.Select_HP()
        self.Select_BD()

    def get_combobox(self, index):
        if index == 1:
            cb_bd_list.addItem(" ")
            cb_bd_list.addItem("correct")
            cb_bd_list.addItem("board")
            cb_bd_list.addItem("list")
        elif index == 2:
            cb_bd_list.addItem(" ")
            cb_bd_list.addItem("correct2")
            cb_bd_list.addItem("board2")
            cb_bd_list.addItem("list2")

    def Select_HP(self):
        cb_hp_list = self.ui.Homepage_List
        cb_hp_list.addItem(" ")
        cb_hp_list.addItem("HP address 1",1)
        cb_hp_list.addItem("HP address 2",2)
        cb_hp_list.addItem("HP address 3",3)


    def Select_BD(self):
        cb_bd_list = self.ui.Board_List
        current_hp = self.ui.Homepage_List.activated.connect(self.get_combobox)
```

when I ran that code, I got cb_bd_list - invalid error.

Comment: If your problem is solved, you can post your solution as an answer, and accept it, so that others see that your question is closed. otherwise, you can also just close your question yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it is a shame you did not supply a Minimally Reproducible Example then I could have shown what you might have been doing wrong but here is a minimalistic working version of what I think you were trying to accomplish.

```
from sys import exit as sysExit

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QComboBox, QHBoxLayout, QLabel

class CentralPanel(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.Parent = parent

        self.cbxHPList = QComboBox()
        self.cbxHPList.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.ChangeBDList)
        self.cbxBDList = QComboBox()

        HBox = QHBoxLayout()
        HBox.addWidget(self.cbxHPList)
        HBox.addWidget(QLabel('   '))
        HBox.addWidget(self.cbxBDList)
        HBox.addStretch(1)

        self.setLayout(HBox)

    def ChangeBDList(self, Index):
        self.Parent.UpdateBDList(Index)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('TestIt')
        self.resize(100,100)

        self.HPList = {0:' ', 1:'HP Address 1', 2:'HP Address 2', 3:'HP Address 3'}
        self.BDList1 = [' ', 'First',  'Board1', 'List1']
        self.BDList2 = [' ', 'Second', 'Board2', 'List2']
        self.BDList3 = [' ', 'Third',  'Board2', 'List3']

        self.CenterPane = CentralPanel(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.CenterPane)

        self.SetHome()

    def SetHome(self):
        self.CenterPane.cbxHPList.clear()
        for key in self.HPList.keys():
            self.CenterPane.cbxHPList.insertItem(key, self.HPList[key])

    def UpdateBDList(self, Index):
        ListUsed = []
        if Index == 1:
            ListUsed = self.BDList1
        elif Index == 2:
            ListUsed = self.BDList2
        elif  Index == 3:
            ListUsed = self.BDList3

        self.CenterPane.cbxBDList.clear()
        if len(ListUsed) > 0:
            Indx = 0
            for Item in ListUsed:
                self.CenterPane.cbxBDList.addItem(Item)
                Indx += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainThred = QApplication([])

    MainGUI = MainWindow()
    MainGUI.show()

    sysExit(MainThred.exec_())
```